# Build are not tagged as unstable when unit test fails

Tags: xcode, hudson

I have added a new job in my hudson server which builds the project with a makefile.

Execute shell command:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd $JOB_NAME
make
```

My makefile looks like this

```
SDK_31 = iphonesimulator3.1
TARGET_DEV = myProject
TARGET_TEST = unitTest

all: debug
debug:
        xcodebuild -sdk ${SDK_31} -target "${TARGET_DEV}" -configuration Debug
        xcodebuild -sdk ${SDK_31} -target "${TARGET_TEST}" -configuration Debug

clean:
        xcodebuild -alltargets clean
        rm -rf build
```

But when hudson build the projects, some unit tests fail but the build is tagged as successful.

What should I have to do to have an "unstable project" ?

Best regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should configure Hudson to record unit test results, by enabling the 'Publish Junit test result report' post-build action.

[post-build actions http://img141.imageshack.us/img141/5136/hudsonjunit.png](http://img141.imageshack.us/img141/5136/hudsonjunit.png)

---

*Update*: If you can't get JUnit XML output, you should be able to use the [Text-finder plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Text-finder+Plugin) to change the build status:

> This plugin lets you search keywords in the files you specified and use that to mark the build as success or a failure.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

As it is not a java project, I do not use JUnit for my unit test, so a do not have TEst report XMLs. But maybe I need a plugin to use my unit test result in hudson build state. I'll check this.

Regards,

Comment: How does your build signal failure then?

Comment: Actually the build result in console looks like:

--------------------
Test Suite '/Users/user/Documents/workspace/iPhone/sandbox/app/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/unitTest.app' finished at 2009-09-17 13:44:44 +0200.
Executed 4 tests, with 1 failures (1 unexpected) in 1.055 (1.055) seconds

...

** BUILD SUCCEEDED **
--------------------------


It seems that I should use plugins like Hudson Text-finder plugin and Warnings plugin to get this unit test failures.

Regards

Comment: Right, I added the text finder plugin. Does xcode save the test results in a file of some sort?

Comment: I configured text finder plugin to parse console output and it works.

Answer (score 1):

I found this handy ruby script by Christian Hedin that converts the output of OCUnit tests (the format used by Xcode) into JUnit xml files (the format used by Hudson).

You can grab the script on github:
http://github.com/ciryon/OCUnit2JUnit

and for an explanation of how to use it, here's his blog post about it:
http://blog.jayway.com/2010/01/31/continuos-integration-for-xcode-projects/

Basically, you pipe xcodebuild into ocunit2junit.rb with a command like this:

```
/usr/bin/xcodebuild -target UnitTests | /usr/local/bin/ocunit2junit.rb
```

and it places the xml files into a test-reports folder that it creates at the root of your project folder. Then tell Hudson to copy the `test-reports/*.xml` artifacts as the JUnit results and you're set.

This setup will allow Hudson to correctly identify if a unit test has passed or failed and correctly mark the stability of the build.

I've been using it for a month now and it works great. The setup was very simple.

Comment: I'd suggest redirecting stderr so that build errors are picked up in the parser and the build can fail properly: /usr/bin/xcodebuild -target UnitTests 2>&1 | /usr/local/bin/ocunit2junit.rb

Comment: That would be a nice addition. :)